# pass URL containing query string as a query string

Tags: javascript, php, regex, codeigniter

I want to let system user to pass URL containing query string as query string. so I can find a matched record from database.

for example : 
the url is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/xxx/?type=3&theater
```

passing this as below:

```
https://example.com/report?search=https://www.facebook.com/xxx/?type=3&theater
```

what I need is extracting the value of the 'search' GET parameter via php or javascript.

PS. I can't use urlencode() since the user will pass this directly

Comment: you've tagged php and javascript. you want a solution in which?

Comment: both are ok @Alex

Answer (score 0):

I hope, i have understood what you exactly need.

```
function parse() {
   const url = new URL(window.location.href);
   console.log(url.searchParams.get('search'));
   console.log(url);
}
parse();
```

This will help you a lote [URL MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

Comment: unfortunately, this will return https://www.facebook.com/xxx/?type without &theater part

Answer (score 0):

A php solution would look like:

```
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $parse = parse_url($url);
    if (!isset($parse['query']) || empty($parse['query'])) {
        exit('query not found');
    }
    $query = str_replace('search=', '', $parse['query']);
    echo $query;
```

Comment: if I have the ability to pass the URL via code all the issue will be solved by using urlencode. actually, I want to read this from $_GET

Comment: you didn't make that very clear. ive updated the code

Comment: thank you, but here $_GET['search'] will not including 'theater' since it will be defined as another $_GET

Comment: oh i finally get your issue. ok, one more time i've updated the code.